# SOAPUI transfer data from excel file to request array

Tags: soapui

I'm using SOAPUI to test webservices. All testdata is kept in excelfiles. How can I transfer data from a cell in excel to an array item in a request? It would be great to get to know how to fill a variable number of items in an array in a request with data from an excelsheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SoapUI Pro, you can use the datasource step.
If not, you can use this class in a groovy script like a library

You need to download the jar jxl to read Excel files:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxl2612jar.htm

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class readExcelToArray 
{
    def log
    def context
    def testRunner
     def String inputFile;
     def String[][] data = null;

    def readExcelToArray(logIn,contextIn,testRunnerIn){
        this.log = logIn
        this.context = contextIn
        this.testRunner = testRunnerIn
    }

    public String[][] getData() 
    {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setInputFile(String inputFile) 
    {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    //function to get une check if a value if present in the column A (column 0)
    public int getIndex(String itemName)
    {
        def items = itemName.toLowerCase().tokenize("-");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.data[0].size(); i++)
        {
                for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++){
                def item = items[j].trim();
                    if (item.equals(this.data[0][i].toLowerCase())){
                    return i;
                }
                }
        } 
        return -1;
    }


    public String[][] read() throws IOException  
    {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        Workbook w;

        try 
        {
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet


            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            data = new String[sheet.getColumns()][sheet.getRows()];
            // Loop over first 10 column and lines
            // log.info(sheet.getColumns() +  " " +sheet.getRows());
            for (int j = 0; j <sheet.getColumns(); j++) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) 
                {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                    data[j][i] = cell.getContents();
                  //  System.out.println(cell.getContents());
                }
            }
/*
            for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <data[j].length; i++) 
                {
                    log.info(data[j][i]);
                }
            } 
*/
        } 
        catch (BiffException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return data;
    }


}

context.setProperty( "readExcelToArray", new readExcelToArray( log, context, testRunner) )
```

And you can use your class like this in you script:

```
//initialize you var project here before
def project = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().getProject()
def library = project.getTestSuiteByName("Scripts");
def module = library.testCases["excelReader"].testSteps["readExcelToArray"]
module.run(testRunner, context)
this.readExcelToArray = context.readExcelToArray
this.readExcelToArray.setInputFile("pathToExcelFile.xls");
def r = this.readExcelToArray.read();

//a functionnal example
if(this.readExcelToArray.getIndex(this.context.getTestCase().name) == -1 || r[0][1] != "valueToTest"){
    log.error("Error")
            }
```

Please check the getIndex function before use it, I modified for my case but it like an example.